# uninitialized constant HomeController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ok, I've been following:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Here are the steps I've had to accomplish so far:

```
rails new survey
<install the script stuff he includes>
rails g nifty:layout
rails g nifty:scaffold survey name:string
rake db:migrate
```

I updated routes.rb to point to home#index (rather then the welcome#index that it was) and deleted public/index.html

When I try to run rails server and go to my local host, I get the following error.
    uninitialized constant HomeController

I'm lost and have no clue what this means.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

OK, So I fixed that problem, I guess where I'm confused is where should my routes point to to ge to see the survey that I just created using the above commands. right now I'm pointing to my home#index, where should that point to?

Edit #2: Contents of Surveys_controller.rb

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])
    if @survey.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created survey."
      redirect_to @survey
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

 def edit
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    if @survey.update_attributes(params[:survey])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated survey."
      redirect_to @survey
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @survey.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed survey."
    redirect_to surveys_url
  end
end
```

Comment: What are the contents of /app/controllers/* and what does your routes.rb file look like?

Comment: app/controllers contains application_controller, home_controller, and surveys_controller, (I'm assuming home_controller didn't exist until I ran the command I "answered" below), looking in surveys_controller, didn't give me any indication what routes.rb should look like, I've tried surveys#new, survey#index, and a few other iterations now, and still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try runnin `rake routes` from the command line to see which routes you do have avalailable

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With routes.rb pointing to `home#index`, it needs a HomeController in you app/controllers folder.

If you follow the tutorial exactly, you can point to just `survey#index`.  Take a look at surveys.rb in app/controllers to see what pages are available.  They were generated with the niffty_scaffold script.

Comment: THank you, I figured out that part just a few moments ago, but I am still not sure what I need to point my routes.rb to to see the survey that is supposed to be generated....should I point it to "survey" and that's it?

Comment: No dice, I tried surveys#new, and get a undefined method for new error.

Comment: I added in my code for the controller if that will help, surveys doesnt work for some reason either returns the error: ArgumentError

missing :action

Rails.root: /home/onaclov/ECE595/survey
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Comment: what happens if you got to <site_root>/surveys/ ?

Comment: well I'm hosed now, I tried downloading the source and looking at that, and when I try to restart my rails server, it says "missing :action" and when I try db:migrate same thing....

Comment: if you didnt change anything too much, try the tutorial again exactly as it says.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out when you try to point to home#index, it needs to have something there, simply running

```
rails generate controller home index
```

fixes that problem.

Comment: "it needs to have something there" what even means? would you please be more clear?

Comment: I'll be honest its been 7 years, I used rails for like a week in a class at that time, at this time I can onlyspeculate that when rails was running and it uses it's search through pathing you need to generate a controller for home#index and the above command does that, but again 7 years ago. Don't forget

Answer (score 3):

stick something like this in your application.html.erb file

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
<%= link_to "Surveys", surveys_path %>
```

The code will blow up if you don't have those routes working but otherwise you should be able to see your surveys by clicking on the button for them

Your routes.rb file should contain the following:

```
resources :surveys
root :to => "home#index"
```

You can view all surveys by going to localhost:3000/surveys

Comment: NoMethodError in SurveysController#index
undefined method `all' for Survey:Module  -- this is the error I get on the page...